# How to address Jquery Selector with Variable

Tags: php, jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

I have a div with a class of boxcatID that has html changed from a jquery script. The problem is that my particular page has many of these divs, so my script of course affects all of them when it should only affect the one.

So to fix this I added a variable of catID to the class name like so boxcatID + catID which comes out to boxcatID1 for example.

Now in my jquery script I need to address the specific div that I am working on so it may be boxcatID1 or even boxcatID30. So I have this as the jquery:

```
 $(".boxcatID"+catID).html( singleValues + glyphLeft);
```

but this throws an error

```
 Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .boxcatID1;
```

These divs are created from a loop in my database. So 30 records will mean 30 divs.

```
 <div class="boxcatID<?php echo $cat_id; ?>">TEXT HERE</div>
```

So how can I address this one single div that I am working on if for example I want to change the TEXT HERE?

Here is the original code:

```
glyphLeft = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" data-unicode="e008"></span>';
            function displayValsL() {

                catID = dp(this).attr("catID");
                console.log("catID is " + catID);
                var singleValues = dp( "select.selectbox-listL" ).val();
                var boxcat = '#boxcatID'+catID;

                dp("#boxcatID"+catID).html( singleValues + glyphLeft);
                var pic = "images/players/" + dp('option:selected' , this).attr("id") + ".png";
                dp(".img-left").attr("src", pic);
                nameValue1 = dp('option:selected' , this).val();
                enableButton();
            }
            dp( "select.selectbox-listL" ).change( displayValsL );
```

PHP

```
<div class="selectbox-wrapper left">
                    <div class="selectboxTopL" id="boxcatID<?php echo $cat_id; ?>" catID='<?php echo $cat_id; ?>'>
                        Player 1 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" data-unicode="e008"></span>
                    </div> <!-- END selectboxTop -->
                    <select  class="selectbox-listL" catID='<?php echo $cat_id; ?>' size="6">

                        <?php
                            $query2 = "SELECT first_name,last_name, playerID, categoryID FROM Players WHERE categoryID = '$cat_id' ORDER BY last_name";
                            $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);

                            if($result2 === FALSE) { 
                                die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
                            }

                            //fetch tha data from the database
                            while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {

                                $playerID = $row2['playerID'];
                                $playerFN = $row2['first_name'];
                                $playerLN = $row2['last_name'];
                                $playerCatID = $row2['categoryID'];

                                echo '<option id="'. $playerFN . $playerLN .'" value="' . $playerFN ." ". $playerLN . '">' . $playerFN . " " . $playerLN . '</option>';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div><!-- END selectbox-wrapper -->
```

Comment: try to alert(catID) and check what data are display

Comment: The catID is correct for every div. It even shows up correct in  FireBug.

Comment: You can also see in the Error message that jquery received the correct div .boxcatID1 where "1" is the variable catID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you have a trailing `;` in the `class` attribute of your HTML, therefore the selector doesn't match. You just need to move the `;` inside the PHP code block. The hanging `'` can be removed too.

Change this:

```
<div class="boxcatID<?php echo $cat_id ?>;"'>TEXT HERE</div>
```

to this

```
<div class="boxcatID<?php echo $cat_id; ?>">TEXT HERE</div>
```

Better yet, remove the need for incremental classes by traversing the DOM from the element which raised the event this code runs under.

Comment: This did fix the Error but not the problem.  When I do actions with div boxcatID20 it makes changes to boxcatID1 for example.  If I am working with boxcatID1 then that is all that should be changed.

Comment: In that case your JS `catID` variable does not hold the value you expect. It's not possible to debug that with the little code you've shown. If you can add a more complete example we might be able to help.

Comment: "Better yet, remove the need for incremental classes by traversing the DOM from the element which raised the event this code runs under."  HUH?

Comment: If I could get rid of incremental that would be great!

Comment: If you could show more of your HTML and CSS I can show you how.

Comment: Ok I edited it. I just did not want to get downvoted right out of SO because of too much code.

Comment: Too much code won't get you downvotes :) Could you also include the `select` element itself.

Comment: as you can see, I am struggling with identifying a single div. The incremental is messing things up. The selectors are a result of trying to figure out how to address the single div

Comment: Hey Rory, thank you very much for using the correct terminology "Traversing DOM." That gave me the key words needed to research it and solve it myself.